# Load js files after ajax inclusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

This is the deal, i'm importing some php files, one of the files has a slider, this slider requires .js files.

But when i make the ajax call, the file is imported but the js files aren't. Is this supposed to be like this?

I tried this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);


window.onload=function(){


$(".cs_article").append('<p>Tdkasdlasdlkamsdklasmdasdaest</p>');

$.getScript('js/jquery.ennui.contentslider.js');

$.getScript('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');

};
```

Kinda works, well, the append works on the DOM even with it being already loaded, but i can't get the scripts to run...

I've done my homework, searched on google, and found several ways of importing the scripts, but all end up with the same result...

Comment: uhm, first, why are you using such old jquery and js libs?

Comment: if you import some php you could just echo the `<script src="..."></script>` tags right?

Comment: @SpYk3HH It's the version needed by the slider, on the main page i have the latest version. But the version that is loaded on the header of the index doesn't seem to cause any effect on the file loaded with ajax.

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn , the echo is not needed, it would result on the same thing just having the html on the header with that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works 
https://github.com/chriso/load.js

Answer (score 1):

Bind your `window.onload` function to `yourjQueryScriptTag.onload` instead; before setting the src and appending it to the DOM, since onload may fire before jQuery is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/5SbXc/

Also, you may want to consider upgrading to a newer version of jQuery if possible.